# Credit card expiry date validation in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

HTML code:

```
<tr>
    <td><label for="expiry_day">Expiry date(MM/YYYY):<span id="imp">*</span></label></td>
    <td>
    <select id="expiry_month" tabindex="4">
    <optgroup label="Month">
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select>

    <select id="expiry_year" tabindex="5">
    <optgroup label="Year">
    <script>generate_year();</script>   
    </optgroup>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function generate_year()                    /*For generate cc year*/
    {
        for (var i = 2014; i <= 2104; i++)

        {
            document.write ("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>");
        }   
    }

        function val_cc () {          

        var expiry_month = document.getElementById("expiry_month").value;
        var expiry_year = document.getElementById("expiry_year").value;
        var today = new Date();
        var expiry_date = today.setFullYear(expiry_year, expiry_month);

        if (today.getTime() > expiry_date.getTime())

        {
            alert ("\u2022Expiry month and year cannot be blank/Expiry month and year is before today month and year.");

            return false;
        }
}
```

These codes are basically used to validate the expiry date for credit card.For example,if today is March 2014 and the user chooses February 2014,I want the form to return false.However,if he chooses April 2014,I want the form to return true and proceed to the next page.If there are mistakes,can you please point them out and do a simple explanation?

Comment: where is the function for validation? put your validation code in a function

Comment: Sorry,it was my mistake and the correction is made.

Comment: where is your expiry_date in your program

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: Good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75975495/386579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update values from select-boxes every time user changes values, please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shershen08/wcFC4/

```
function runMyCheck(){
//update value every run
var expiry_month = document.getElementById("expiry_month").value;
var expiry_year = document.getElementById("expiry_year").value;

var today = new Date();
var selDate = new Date();

if (today.getTime() > selDate.setFullYear(expiry_year, expiry_month)){
 //too late
    alert ("\u2022Expiry month and year cannot be blank/Expiry month and year is before today month and year.");
    return false;
} else {
//do good stuff...

}
```

}

Comment: Actually what is wrong with my codes?Because my codes seem similar to yours.How about if I want the error message appears after the user clicks 'submit'?

Comment: then you could add handler to you from tag - <form onsubmit="runMyCheck()"> instead of using <select onchange="runMyCheck()">

Comment: This code has an error, the expiry_month when passed to setFullYear is expected to be zero based, (January is 0, not 1 as you might expect from a sane language). So your check will be off by a month.

Comment: there should be an error with this code. As in Javascript Month start from 0 to 11 and here used is 1 to 12

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
var today = new Date();
var expDate = new Date($("#cart-expyear").val(),($("#cart-expmonth").val()-1)); // JS Date Month is 0-11 not 1-12 replace parameters with year and month
if(today.getTime() > expDate.getTime()) {
   console.log("Your Card is expired. Please check expiry date.");
}
```

Comment: Or you can use 
var today = new Date();
var expDate = new Date($("#cart-expyear").val(),($("#cart-expmonth").val())); // JS Date Month is 0-11 not 1-12 replace parameters with year and month
if(today.getTime() >= expDate.getTime())

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
 function generate_year()                    /*For generate cc year*/
    {
        for (var i = 2014; i <= 2104; i++)

        {
            var x = document.getElementById("expiry_year");
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = i;
            option.value=i
            x.add(option);
        }   
    }
    var expiry_month = document.getElementById("expiry_month").value;
       alert(expiry_month);
    var expiry_year = document.getElementById("expiry_year").value;
    var today = new Date();
    var expiry_date = today.setFullYear(expiry_year, expiry_month);
     var from=new Date();
    if (today.getTime() >from.setFullYear(expiry_year, expiry_month) )
    {
        alert ("\u2022Expiry month and year cannot be blank/Expiry month and year is before today month and year.");

       //return false;
    }
```