# How to you validate expiration date in a credit card form?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner in web development and I have to submit inside a form the expiration date of my credit card in a format of MM-DD-YYYY . I have written some code that  recognizes if a string is in this specific format . However I want to check if the date has already been expired and is less than the current date we have  and check each element in the format exclusively (ex . check if MM > 12).I would appreciate your help with guiding me to solve this task.
Thank you in advance .

My code :

```js
function checkdate(){

 var dateReg = /^\d{2}([./-])\d{2}\1\d{4}$/ //MM-DD-YYYY format
 var date = document.getElementById("date");
 
 //i can just check if my element is date format
 if(!date.value.match(dateReg)){
    
 alert("not a date ");
 return false;
 
 }
 
 
 return true;
 

}
```

```html
 <label for "expiration-date"> Card Expiration Date </label> 
 <input type = "text" name = "exp-date" id = "date" placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY" required>

<button type = "submit" class = "submitbtn" onclick= "return checkdate()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: As of my knowledge .. credit card form should not have a day field but only month and year fields. like MM/YYYY

Comment: @Anees Ijaz I know but we have been asked for expiration date in this assignment

Comment: A similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27055165/6813906)

Comment: @Jeferson Macedo I have seen it but it does not cover the date part only the month and year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string to a `Date` object and use the `<` and `>` operators to compare it with the current date.

```html
<label for "expiration-date"> Card Expiration Date </label> 
<input type = "text" name = "exp-date" id = "date" placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY" required>

<button type = "submit" class = "submitbtn" onclick= "return checkdate()">Submit</button>

<script>
  function checkdate(){
    var dateReg = /^\d{2}([./-])\d{2}\1\d{4}$/ //MM-DD-YYYY format
    var date = document.getElementById("date");
    var expDate = new Date(date.value)
    var currDate = new Date()

    if (!date.value.match(dateReg)) {
      alert("not a date ");
      return false;
      
    } else if (expDate < currDate) {
      alert("Card expired");
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can parse the date and compare it with the current date.

```js
function checkdate(){

 var dateReg = /^\d{2}([./-])\d{2}\1\d{4}$/ //MM-DD-YYYY format
 var date = document.getElementById("date");
 
 //i can just check if my element is date format
 if(!date.value.match(dateReg)){
    
 alert("not a date ");
 return false;
 
 }else{
  const date1 = new Date(date.value);
  const date2 = new Date();
  const diffTime = (date2 - date1);
  const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  
  if(diffDays > 0){
      alert("card expired");
  }else{
    alert("card valid");
  }
   
 }
 
 
 return true;
 

}
```

```html
<label for "expiration-date"> Card Expiration Date </label> 
 <input type = "text" name = "exp-date" id = "date" placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY" required>

<button type = "submit" class = "submitbtn" onclick= "return checkdate()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this piece of code will help you

```js
function checkdate(){
var dateReg = /^\d{2}([./-])\d{2}\1\d{4}$/ //MM-DD-YYYY format
 var date = document.getElementById("date");
 
 //i can just check if my element is date format
 if(!date.value.match(dateReg)){
  
 alert("not a date ");
 return false;
 
 }else{
   var todaydate = new Date();
   todaydate = todaydate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
   console.log(todaydate);
   console.log(date.value)
   console.log(new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0));
   if(new Date(date.value).setHours(0,0,0,0)<todaydate){
    alert("entered date is less than today date");
   } else{
    alert("entered date is greater than today date");
   }
 }
 
 
 return true;
 

}
```

```html
 <label for "expiration-date"> Card Expiration Date </label> 
 <input type = "text" name = "exp-date" id = "date" placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY" required>

<button type = "submit" class = "submitbtn" onclick= "return checkdate()">Submit</button>
```

think the below piece of code will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the date to an Array to easily realize comparisons with each date member based on your validation needs:

```js
const array = data.split('-').map(v => Number(v)) // [M, D, Y]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var current_date = new Date();
if ((current_date.getDay() > date.getDay()) && (current_date.getFullYear() > date.getFullYear()) && (current_date.getMonth() > date.getMonth()))
{
alert("Expired ");
}
```

Comment: When you say transform to a date what do you mean ?

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake, could you try the above script

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Comment: @TechWisdom still an answer, though. [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/1324)

Comment: @PaulRoub Thank you a lot.